# Send arguments from ts file to another @Input Component

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to have a register forms and to have a Dialog when the users press on the submit button.
I created two component: RegisterComponent and DialogComponent.

My Dialog is simple:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-dialog',
  templateUrl: './dialog.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dialog.component.sass'],
})
export class DialogComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<DialogComponent>) {}

  @Input()
  m_title: string;
  m_description: string;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log(this.m_title);
    console.log(this.m_description);
  }

  onNoClick(): void {
    this.dialogRef.close();
  }
}
```

I have two @Input that i want to use inside.
So in my registerComponent, i can call the Dialog Component from my register.ts but i dont know how to give the input as arguments.

My registerComponent:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-register',
  templateUrl: './register.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./register.component.sass'],
})
export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit {
  public registerForm: FormGroup;
  public matcher = new MyErrorStateMatcher();
  public dialog: MatDialogRef<DialogComponent>;

  constructor(
    private _authService: AuthService,
    private _formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private _route: ActivatedRoute,
    private _router: Router,
    private _dialog: MatDialog
  ) {}

  /*
   * Initiation of the component
   */
  ngOnInit() {
    this.registerForm = this._formBuilder.group(
      {
        email: ['', [Validators.required]],
        username: ['', [Validators.required]],
        password: ['', [Validators.required]],
        confirmPassword: [''],
      },
      { validator: this.checkPasswords }
    );
  }

  /*
   * Submit the forms
   */
  onSubmit(): void {
    console.log('On submit');
  }

  onRegister(): void {
    console.log('On register');
    this.dialog = this._dialog.open(DialogComponent, {
      disableClose: true
    });
  }

  /*
   * Custom validator for checking the passwords
   */
  checkPasswords(group: FormGroup) {
    let password = group.get('password').value;
    let confirmPassword = group.get('confirmPassword').value;

    return password === confirmPassword ? null : { notSame: true };
  }

  /*
  * Get username content in my register.component.html file
   */
  get username() {
    return this.registerForm.get('username');
  }

  /*
  * Get email content in my register.component.html file
   */
  get email() {
    return this.registerForm.get('email');
  }

  /*
  * Get password content in my register.component.html file
   */
  get password() {
    return this.registerForm.get('password');
  }

  /*
  * Get confirmPassword content in my register.component.html file
   */
  get confirmPassword() {
    return this.registerForm.get('confirmPassword');
  }
}
```

In my registerComponent in theonRegister(), i can call my Dialog so i try to give my input like:

I tried:

```
this.dialog = this._dialog.open(DialogComponent, {
     disableClose: true,
     m_title: "test",
     m_description: "test"
   })
```

I also tried:

```
this.dialog = this._dialog.open(DialogComponent("test", "test"), {
      disableClose: true
    })
```

Do you have any tips ?

Comment: What is the issue in your first approach where you passing data as arguments of open method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Angular Material documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/examples) states that the constructor handles data injection in the following manner:

```js
constructor(
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<DialogComponent>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: MyDataModel) {}
```

where `MyDataModel` should be, in your case, something like:

```js
export interface MyDataModel {
  m_title: string,
  m_description: string
}
```

All the data you pass as payload will be held inside the injected `data` object. Therefore, you do not need the `@Input()` properties.

The way you should pass the data to the dialog:

```js
this.dialog = this._dialog.open(DialogComponent, {
     disableClose: true,
     data: {
       m_title: "test",
       m_description: "test"
     }
   })
```

*Side note*: The `@Input()` decorator must be used for **each** property you want as "input".